# Retrieving column value in table2 via same ID in table1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL query that returns overdue assignments

```
SELECT DUE_DATE, 
       SUBJECT, 
       ASSIGNMENT, 
       STUDENT_NAME, 
       TEACHER_NAME
FROM(SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.due_date AS due_date,
            a.subject AS subject,
            a.assignment AS assignment,
            a.student_name AS student_name,
            a.student_id AS student_id,
            a.teacher_name AS teacher_name,
            a.teacher_id AS teacher_id
     FROM DB.ASSIGNMENT a, 
          DB.ALL b, 
     WHERE (trunc(a.DATE_CREATED) >= trunc(db.utc_sysdate)))
WHERE((trunc(due_date) < trunc(db.utc_sysdate));
```

and I want to include both the teacher and student emails as additional columns in my SQL query - I was wondering how to map their id in table ASSIGNMENT in order to get their respective emails in table ALL with the existing query I have?

Comment: Your query is incorrect. You need to show us the structure of both tables. Sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

We do lack some information, but - wouldn't your query be like this?

```
select distinct 
  a.due_date,
  a.subject,
  a.assignment,
  a.student_name,
  a.student_email,
  a.teacher_name,
  a.teacher_email 
from db.assignment a join db.all b
  on trunc(a.date_created) >= trunc(b.utc_sysdate)
 and trunc(a.due_date)      < trunc(b.utc_sysdate);
```

What's the difference, if compared to your query?

- your query is invalid

  - comma after `db.all b`
  - the final `where` clause references `db.` "alias" (although it is probably schema name, according to inline view's `from` clause)
- there's no point in aliasing column names using exactly the same name; what's the difference between `a.due_date as due_date` and `a.due_date` itself? None. So don't use it, you're just causing confusion
- as you want to include student's and teacher's e-mail addresses, why don't you just *do that*? Add those columns into the query ...
- it seems that you don't need an inline view; put both `where` conditions into the same query and remove columns you don't need (both `ID`s)